# Disable rotation animation of one subview

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, swift3

I'm trying to disable device orientation animation for just some subviews in my `UIView` subclass. I managed to disable camera preview rotation animation by using this view layer as `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and reacting to `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientation` by changing `layer.connection.videoOrientation`. This works ok, but I also have one subview added that I also want to rotate without animation. Is there some way I can remove this animation for just that subview? Also I can't use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` as it's in `UIViewController`, and I want my `UIView` subclass to work this way without implementing anything additional in the controller. I only have `UIView` functions and `NotificationCenter` to work with.